# React child component not updating parent state

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm using **React** + **Electron** + **Redux** in my app development. I was able to update the parent state from a child component in another case, but now I'm not able to do it, the state is only being updated to the child components.

I know that the reducer action is being called with the right value, but the **parent component** is being rerendered with the wrong one (the previous one), only the sub tree of the child component is being rendered with right value.

### My method:

I'm creating a function (action handler) in the **parent component container**:

```
class CreateExerciseCanvas extends React.Component {

focusOnSection (section) { /* this is the function that i'm refering to */
   store.dispatch(actions.focusOnSection(section))
}
render() {
   return ( 
        <CreateExerciseCanvas 
        focusOnSection={ this.focusOnSection }
        /> 
        )
}
}
const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    return {
        focusOnSection: store.exercise.focusOnSection
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CreateExerciseCanvasContainer)
```

And this function is being passed as a **prop** to the child container:

```
<Index focusOnSection={ this.props.focusOnSection }/>
```

Lastly, the method is being used as an **onClick handler** in the child view. 
Isn't this the right way of updating a parent with **redux** + **react**?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your **this** context to the focusOnSection function in your constructor, or else it doesn't know what **this** is.

Try adding a constructor like so to your CreateExerciseCanvas:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focusOnSection = this.focusOnSection.bind(this);
}
```

This is probably this most annoying part about using ES6 classes.

Comment: I'm doing it in my view `import CreateExerciseCanvas from '../../views/exercise/createExerciseCanvas'`, but after adding it to the container as well, it didn't work either.

Comment: @Pedro, why are you connecting to the container and not to the CreateExerciseCanvas ?

Comment: Well, you're right, I should use the `this.focusOnSection.bind(this)`, but it's not working, even with that change

Answer (score 0):

If you check the value of `this.props` inside `focusOnSection (section)`, you will see that it is `undefined`. This is because `focusOnSection () {}` is the short syntax of `focusOnSection: function () {}`, which is binding `this` to the function, so there is no more `this.props`.

One solution would be hard-binding `this` to the class in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focusOnSection = this.focusOnSection.bind(this);
}
```

The other would be using an arrow function like `focusOnSelection = () => {}` which doesn't bind `this`. This latter solution only works if you are using babel (check the es2015 preset).

Comment: `this.props` is defined, and the action is being fired with right value, as refered in the question, the container is being rendered with the wrong value though. Should I use the _arrow function like_ in the container? Notice that the **container class** is extending a `React.Component`. The sintax that you are proposing is relative to the `React.createClass` method, which is deprecated since the last update, am I wrong?

Comment: What value are you expecting the component to receive? I can only see the focusOnSection action

Comment: My mistake, I've changed the `focusOnSection` method to the right snippet, sorry about that, I'm receiving an `int value`.